# how to git source just in server not in client?

Tags: git, version-control, branch

In my project we don't like each developer to have the source code on their client computer. They should just access it on their own branch folder on the server.

We need to create a repository on the server in this folder:

```
//172.30.12.35/d$/project
```

We have a branch named `sam`, and this developer branch folder is:

```
//172.30.12.35/d$/sam
```

We create the `sam` branch with:

```
git clone //172.30.12.35/d$/project //172.30.12.35/d$/sam
```

on push we got errors. like:

> `fatal: not a valid object name :HEAD`

Comment: Can you explain how could a developer develop without source code?

Comment: if my developer need source code open //172.30.12.35/d$/sam and edit files on server and if need to test //172.30.12.35/sam. but source just in server

Comment: How can 2 guys edit the same file at the same time? And if different developers want to test at the same time different non-compatible code changes? What if a developer wants to test something that might break the app and take some time to get properly working?

Comment: we clone project for each guys but my clone destination in the server. he can also commit changes and push to his branch on the server. i don't like this but my company need.

Comment: Why use git if you aren't going to use it for distributed development? You might as well use Subversion.

Comment: Sounds like mounting the remote directory on the development machines is what you are looking for. Note, that this will always be a performance flaw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want your developers to *fork* the main repository, not *branch*.

**Forking** is a concept, very [popular on GitHub](http://help.github.com/fork-a-repo/), where developers don't have write access to the main repository and instead do work on their own copy of it. The copy is created by [cloning the repository](http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-clone), like in your example. The way they contribute to the main repository is by sending patches, or [pull requests in GitHub's terms](http://help.github.com/send-pull-requests/), that are merged in main code base.

**Branching** in Git does not involve separate copy of the repository, like it does for example in [subversion](http://subversion.tigris.org/), but rather is an entity *within* the repository itself. You can think of it as [a *label* pointing to the latest of a series of successive commits](http://progit.org/book/ch3-1.html).

Comment: thanks, we just need user don't have source code in client, user source code on the server, i know forking and branching and tanks for your description

Comment: In that case you shouldn't use Git, like @erturne suggested. Distributed source control systems like Git build upon the idea of having a local copy of the repository.